# python selenium テーブル内のタグが子要素として並んでいる場合の値取得

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

皆様

お世話になります。
Python+seleniumでクローラーを回しております。
WEBで検索結果のテーブルからデータを抽出しようとしているのですが、取りたい要素にidやclassが割り振られておらず、同じタグが子要素として並んでいるためデータ取得ができません。ご指導をお願いできますでしょうか。

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://suumo.jp/chintai/tokyo/ek_05780/nj_207/"
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
rows = soup.find_all(class_=['cassetteitem'])

for row in rows:
#各テーブルのデータ取得

    　　　　　　　for i in row.find_all(class_=['js-cassette_link']):
        　　　　　#テーブル内のデータの取得

                 i.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='js-cassette_link']td[3]")
```

四苦八苦色々としましたが、driverでxpathのデータ取得は成功しましたが、driverをobjectとしてテーブル内のデータを分解していくと、以下のエラーしかでなくなりました。記載の仕方が悪いのでしょうか？ご指導をお願いします。
⇒TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iは、BeautifulSoupのオブジェクトで、webdriverのオブジェクトではありません。
BeautifulSoupは、find find_all
webdriverは、find_element_by_** find_elements_by_** です。

iのタグに統一性があるなら、
i.div.td[3] とかでいけるかも